# How to start emacs server only if it is not started?

Tags: emacs, configuration, mutt

I'd like to use emacsclient to edit emails in Mutt.

I added this in .emacs

`(server-start)`

And in .muttrc I added

`set editor="emacsclient -nw %s"`

It seems they work.
When I start a second Emacs, it complains there is already a server running so it issues errors. How to make sure to do `(server-start)` only if the server isn't already started?

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The emacs daemon can be started automatically in a very simple manner. Just add this to your .bashrc/.zshrc/whatever

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
```

Now when you invoke `emacsclient` (using either `--tty` or `--create-frame`) the server will be started (with `emacs --daemon`) if it's not already running.

I also find this shell alias handy:

```
alias e='emacsclient --tty'
```

Note that since Emacs 23 this is the preferred way to use Emacs in daemon mode. `(start-server)` is now mostly deprecated.

Comment: This is a nice solution.  `emacsclient -c` also works, and supports graphical clients. However, how would you go about opening a file in an existing emacs frame (say, in another terminal).  Currently, I have a bash script called `e` that checks to see if the first argument is `-o` (for other) and runs `emacsclient` without `-c` if it does.  Is there a better way, using the alias, that you can override the `-t` and cause an existing frame to open the file?

Comment: @edam not sure if you found your answer, but it sounds like you want the -t switch to emacsclient.  It's a bit hard to tell because your comment seems to blur the distinction between a non-graphical emacs instance in a terminal, with a windowed graphical instance.  -t is for the former, -c is for the latter.

Comment: @Daniel: I got it sussed. [Here is my script that I start emacs with](http://pastebin.com/bxmMTTjr). You can run it like this: `$ e -o /path/to/file` to send the file to another emacs already running elsewhere (which is useful).  And it detects when it's being run inside a shell in emacs (the results are bad otherwise!).  It always runs emacs in a terminal, although you can easily remove the `-nw` at the end to change this.

Comment: Can you provide some reference for the claim that "this is the preferred way to use Emacs in daemon mode" and that "`(start-server)` is now mostly deprecated"?  I don't see that mentioned in the most recent documentation, nor anywhere else.  Thanks.

Comment: Agreed i am not sure this is true, when i start emacs with -c or -t it actually tells me to start the server. "To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start"." so that makes it sound like thats the preferred way.

Comment: To add to the request for reference of best practice, I would love to have some more information about exactly why this works the way it does.

Answer (score 72):

This code starts the server only if it's not running:

```
(load "server")
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))
```

Comment: This is the only option that works on Windows currently since `emacs --daemon` says _This platform does not support the -daemon flag._

Comment: @legends2k, on Windows you can also do `emacs --funcall server-start`, but I agree this is better and works cross-platform.

Comment: When I this lines to init.el, `M-x` returns `Error reading from stdin`. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: I found that `(load "server")` resulted in errors when trying to use magit (in particular, on Windows).  Using `(require 'server)` instead prevents these errors.

Answer (score 16):

A bit of a late answer, but here is the solution that works for me.  Whenever I start emacsclient, I use `emacsclient -a '' -c`  The `-a ''` tells emacsclient to attempt to connect to an existing server, and if no server exists, start one then connect to it.

Comment: The `-a ''` option is great. Note that `-c` always create a new frame. If typically want to edit the file in the existing emacs frame, so I omit this option

Answer (score 8):

Avoid the problem alltogether via

```
emacs --daemon
```

in any shell or terminal so that Emacs runs in the background.  That way `emacsclient` is always happy as there is always an Emacs server to connect to.

This being Emacs, there is also a function that starts the server only when needed but I can't quite recall its name right now. I use the `--daemon` option happily quite happily myself.

Comment: I cannot agree more, the beauty of `emacs --daemon` shines when I put this in my standard Startup Applications Prefs in Ubuntu `/usr/bin/emacs --daemon` and whenever I startup my machine I can swiftly jot down a floating idea to my capture template in emacs by hitting `Super + I` (a keyboard shortcut to `emacsclient -c --eval '(progn (org-capture) (delete-other-windows) (setq-local kill-buffer-hook (lambda () (delete-frame))))'`) and I get a nice emacs frame telling me what annoying ideas you want to get rid of off my head.

Comment: should we run `emacs --daemon` as `emacs --daemon &` on the background?

Comment: I think it disappears by itself so if you say `emacs --daemon` you do get your prompt back. Try it, and follow-up with `emacsclient -nw` !

Comment: `emacsclient -nw` keep returns `emacsclient: connect: Connection refused` error message not sure why

Comment: Then you have no daemon runnning.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`

```sh
if ! ps -e -o args | grep -q '^emacs --daemon$'; then
  emacs --daemon
else
  echo "Emacs server Online"
fi
```

---

**Update:** now I prefer to use this line instead:

```sh
if ! ps -e -o args | grep -i 'emacs' | grep 'daemon'; then
```

because the process name will depend on your machine or the way you installed emacs.

---

Now your shell will start the deamon on startup, but only if it is not already running. Less wait time when you first run `emacsclient -t`, and it is faster than letting `emacs --daemon` check if it's already running.

As an alternative you could simply add:

```sh
eval 'emacsclient -e "(server-running-p)"'
```

Comment: I needed to use `ps -xe -o args | grep -q '^emacs --daemon'` on FreeBSD, because without the x option ps would not show emacs --daemon, and it also prints the version number, so I dropped the $ on the end.